# Como organizar por proximidade usando PHP?

Tags: php

Tenho alguns locais cadastrados no banco de dados e cada um deles tem a longitude e latitude. Quando o usuário entra no site, peço para que ele informe sua geolocalização. Estou usando a [biblioteca PHPGeo](https://github.com/mjaschen/phpgeo) para fazer o cálculo da distância entre cada um, mas como eu posso organizar esse resultado?

Ex: Local 1, Local 2, Local 3

Eu estou mais próximo do **Local 2**, depois **Local 3** e depois o **Local 1**.

Como faço para organizar isso?

Comment: Você está fazendo um select em todo BD e depois trazendo todos os resultados, para filtrar no PHP qual o mais próximo?

Answer (score 11):

Partindo da própria PHPGeo, conforme mencionado na pergunta:

### Fórmula de Vincenty

```
<?php
   use Location\Coordinate;
   use Location\Distance\Vincenty;
   $coordenada1 = new Coordinate( -23.575, -46.658 );
   $coordenada2 = new Coordinate( -21.279, -44.297 );
   $calculadora = new Vincenty();
   echo $calculadora->getDistance( $coordenada1, $coordenada2 );
?>
```

### [Fórmula de Haversine](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fórmula_de_Haversine)

A [fórmula de Haversine](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fórmula_de_Haversine) é bem mais rápida de se calcular, porém, menos precisa.

```
<?php
   use Location\Coordinate;
   use Location\Distance\Haversine;
   $coordenada1 = new Coordinate( -23.575, -46.658 );
   $coordenada2 = new Coordinate( -21.279, -44.297 );
   $calculadora = new Haversine();
   echo $calculadora->getDistance( $coordenada1, $coordenada2 );
?>
```

[GitHub - PHPGeo](https://github.com/mjaschen/phpgeo#calculations)

### Calculando a distância da origem a vários pontos, e ordenando:

Para ordenar os resultados, você pode partir do ponto de referência, e num loop armazenar as distâncias calculadas em um array, para depois ordená-los:

```
<?php
    $origem       = new Coordinate( -22.155, -45.158 );

    // Lembre-se de inicializar as arrays de acordo com seu código
    $nome[1] = 'Ponto1';
    $coordenada[1] = new Coordinate( -23.575, -46.658 );

    $nome[2] = 'Ponto2';
    $coordenada[2] = new Coordinate( -21.279, -44.297 );

    $nome[3] = 'Ponto3';
    $coordenada[3] = new Coordinate( -21.172, -44.017 );
    ... etc ...

    // Vamos calcular a distância de todos para a $origem:
    $calculadora = new Haversine();
    $count = count( $coordenada );
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
       $distancia[i] = calculadora->getDistance( $origem, $coordenada[i] );
    }

    // Agora ordenamos os pontos de acordo com a $distancia:
    array_multisort( $distancia, $coordenada, $nome );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você precisa saber a sua localização em coordenadas.
Depois você calcula as distâncias entre o ponto inicial(você) e os outros pontos, utilizando a fórmula de haversine, ou algum recurso da PHPGEO se ela tiver, eu não conheço.
Então você pega o menor valor e pronto, esta é a menor distância, com esta lógica você pode colocar as distâncias num array, assim array[0] -> menor distância, array[1] -> segunda menor distância...