# Verificando filial mais próxima de um CEP

Tags: api, cep, código-postal

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de um curso que possui várias filiais.

Dentro do cadastro eu tenho um campo CEP e gostaria que, por meio deste CEP, ele encontrasse a filial mais próxima. Existe alguma API ou alguma forma de tratar esse problema?

Comment: Você precisa que a filial já seja proposta durante o cadastro no sistema ou é um sistema interno ou é um front-end para clientes??

Comment: É um front-end para clientes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Primeiro, você precisa georeferenciar seus CEPs, e suas unidades, com latitude e longitude. Algumas bases fornecem estes dados, como por exemplo, o **[CEP Aberto](http://cepaberto.com)** (há outras iniciativas neste sentido, cabe uma pesquisada).

O problema maior é que **CEPs não tem uma ligação direta com posicionamento**, apenas uma mera orientação por regiões e sub-regiões de distribuição, o que não serve para muita coisa em uma cidade grande.

Se puder, é **melhor ainda** dar a oportunidade aos usuários do site a escolherem sua posição através de im ponto num mapa, pois os CEPS muitas vezes abrangem áreas extensas, e às vezes até cidades inteiras.

Isto resolvido, precisa organizar sua base pelas unidades mais próximas, como por exemplo, discutido nesta pergunta:

[Como organizar por proximidade usando PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17418/)

Ou mesmo em se tratando de distâncias no território nacional (seja Brasil ou Portugal), os cálculos podem ser simplificados utilizando-se o cálculo de distância tradicional, dado pela fórmula:

```
 distancia = raiz(  ( x2 - x1 )² + ( y2 - y1 )² )
```

pois provavelmente nestes casos a geodésica entre os dois pontos pode ser ignorada, visto que as taxas de erro vão ficar muito aquém de distâncias normais entre duas filiais. E mesmo que ambas sejam próximas, provavelmente seja o caso de retornar ambas, abaixo de uma margem de tolerância.

Comment: Cálculo de distância tradicional. Teorema de Pitágoras.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, se eu editasse e mudasse para "Teorema de Pitágoras" me sentiria compelido a escrever `a² = b² + c²` no lugar. Prefiro a fórmula mastigada para o caso específico mesmo.

Answer (score 7):

Veja se esta informação ajuda em algo:

```
1. x0000-000 (Região)
2. 0×000-000 (Sub-Região)
3. 00×00-000 (Setor)
4. 000×0-000 (Sub-Setor)
5. 0000x-000 (Divisor de sub-setor)
6. 00000-xxx (Identificadores de distribuição)
```

Comment: Mas e a possível matemática para determinar a proximidade? Bastaria uma subtração simples?

Answer (score 1):

Em algumas situações não é conveniente usar uma API de geolocalização para consultar CEP por CEP para comparar suas distâncias, ou os CEPs não são guardados junto às suas coordenadas. Neste caso, é conveniente testar apenas as regiões dos CEPs:

```php
function zip_code_distance(string $input_zip_code, array $zip_codes): array
{
    /**
     * x0000-000 - Região
     * 0×000-000 - Sub-Região
     * 00×00-000 - Setor
     * 000×0-000 - Sub-Setor
     * 0000x-000 - Divisor de sub-setor
     * 00000-xxx - Identificadores de distribuição
     */

    // filtra o cep
    $input = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $input_zip_code);

    // testa por sub região
    $test_length = 2;
    $test_piece = substr($input, 0, $test_length);
    $return_array = [];

    foreach ($zip_codes as $zip_code) {
        if (substr($zip_code, 0, $test_length) == $test_piece) {
            $return_array[] = $zip_code;
        }
    }

    return $return_array;
}
```

No código acima, de algoritmo bem simples, é comparada a sub-região de um CEP com os CEPs de um array de comparação. Quando os dois digitos forem iguais, significa que são da mesma sub-região.

É possível "diminuir" o escopo quando usado `$test_length = 3` ou menor, sendo que irá verificar o setor também.

O código está em PHP, mas pode ser reproduzido em outras linguagens. O mesmo também descarta o uso de API.

Não é recomendado para obter resultados mais precisos. Exemplo prático do código:

```php
zip_code_distance(
    "15050-200",
    [
        "15023-230",
        "12026-100",
        "18300-120",
        "15824-230",
        "05823-120",
        "09250-441"
    ]
);

// saída:
"15023-230",
"15824-230"
```