# Cálculo de distância na Terra: URI - 1721

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como calcular a distância entre pontos da Terra dados latitude e longitude. Quais fórmulas usar pra converter coordenadas esféricas pra cartesiana e vice-versa.

Preciso de ajudar pra resolver um problema do URI: 
https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1721

```
#URI - 1721 - Equidistance
import math

def sphericalDistence(p, q, r):
  #p e q sao pares de coordenadas esfericas (latitude, longitude)
  #r eh o raio da esfera
  return math.acos(math.sin(p[0]) * math.sin(q[0])+ math.cos(p[0]) * math.cos(q[0]) * math.cos(p[1]-q[1]))*r

r = 6378
p = {}
S, La, Lo = input().split()
while S!='#':
      try:
            p[S] = (math.radians(float(La)), math.radians(float(Lo)))#remember of the convert to radians 
        #print('S=', S, ' La Lo = ', p[S])
        S, La, Lo = input().split()       
  except:
        break

#URI
A, B, M = input().split()
while A!='#':
      if not(A in p.keys() and B in p.keys() and M in p.keys()):
            d = '?'
      else:
            p1 = (math.radians(p[M][0]),math.radians(p[M][1]))
            p2 = (math.radians((p[A][0]+p[B][0])/2),math.radians((p[A][1]+p[B][1])/2))
            d = str(sphericalDistence(p1, p2, r))
      #print('d A M = ',(sphericalDistence(p[A], p[M],r)))
      #print('d B M = ',(sphericalDistence(p[B], p[M],r)))
      print('%s is %s km off %s/%s equidistance' %(M, d, A, B))
      A, B, M = input().split()
"""
#UVA    
A, B= input().split()
while A!='#':
      print((sphericalDistence(p[A], p[B],r)))
      A, B = input().split()
"""
```

Comment: Ver: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17444

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro o raio de circunferência da terra em `KM` é de **6371** e não de **6378** como colocaste no exemplo.

Para calcular a distancia entre dois pontos usando `latitude` e `longitude` podes usar a seguinte fórmula [(baseado na fórmula de Haversine)](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine)

```
from math import cos, asin, sqrt
def distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    p = 0.017453292519943295     #Pi/180
    a = 0.5 - cos((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 + cos(lat1 * p) * cos(lat2 * p) * (1 - cos((lon2 - lon1) * p)) / 2
    return 12742 * asin(sqrt(a)) #2*R*asin...
```

Segundo a questão apresentada no link de sua pergunta seria inserir **lat1** e **lon1** as coordenadas de Alice e **lat2** e **lon2** as coordenadas de Bob... você pode dividir o resultado por 2 para encontrar a distancia média (o meio do caminho) entre Alice e Bob.

Comment: O raio ta errado na descrição do problema mesmo.
Não entendi como exatamente usa a função pra gerar a saída, quais pontos usar.

Comment: **lat1** e **lon1** seriam iguais a **p** e **q** de Alice (latitude, longitude) enquanto **lat2** e **lon2** seriam latitude e longitude de Bob. Você não precisa adicionar **r** (raio) porque ele já esta implícito no calculo de retorno como deixei no comentário final `# 2 * R * asin...`, você pode dividir por 2 e arredondar o retorno desta função para chegar na distancia do "meio do caminho" entre Alice e Bob.